# virsh shutdown <vm>: does not work (KVM)

Tags: virtual-machine, centos6, shutdown, kvm, virsh

I've tried looking for a solution to shutdown vm from host in KVM and haven't found any. All I see is `virsh shutdown <vm_name>`, which does not work.

`virsh destroy <vm_name>` works, but that does not stop the VM gracefully. Does anyone know how to do this? (CentOS6)

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [sf].